# Html/css/js find if elements are hovering others

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-physics

I started writing in html/css/js a few months ago and I decided to write a little 2d game whithout any library(like jQuery or else) and it looks like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown",keyDown);
        
        function keyDown(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 39) move(8, 0);
            if(e.keyCode == 37) move(-8, 0);
            if(e.keyCode == 40) move(0, -8);
            if(e.keyCode == 38) move(0, 8);
        }
        
        function move(X,Y) {
            var player=document.getElementById("player")
            var xBrk=Number(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("brick")).getPropertyValue("left").replace('px',""));
            var yBrk=Number(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("brick")).getPropertyValue("bottom").replace('px',""));
            var xWin=Number(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("box")).getPropertyValue("width").replace('px',""))-Number(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("player")).getPropertyValue("width").replace('px',""));
            var yWin=Number(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("box")).getPropertyValue("height").replace('px',""))-Number(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("player")).getPropertyValue("height").replace('px',""));
            var x=Number(getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("left").replace('px',""))+X;
            var y=Number(getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("bottom").replace('px',""))+Y;
            if ((x>=0&&x<=xWin)&&(x!==xBrk||y!==yBrk)) player.style.left=x + "px";
            if ((y>=0&&y<=yWin)&&(x!==xBrk||y!==yBrk)) player.style.bottom=y + "px";
        }
```

```css
#box {
            position:absolute
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            background-color:blue;
            width:512px;
            height:256px;
        }
        #player {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:32px;
            left:136px;
            background-color:red;
            width:8px;
            height:8px;
            z-index:2;
        }
        #world {
            position:relative;
            bottom:0px;
            left:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            z-index:1;
        }
        #brick {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0px;
            left:128px;
            background-color:black;
            width:32px;
            height:32px;
            z-index:1;
        }
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <div id="world">
            <div id="brick"/>
        </div>
        <div id="player"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

When the player and the brick are the same size, the game works fine, but when I change the height or width of the player in the keyDown() function to something smaller then the size of the brick (like 8 and -8) then I move to the brick, the player covers the brick. After a few hours, I understood that it was due to the fact that the code only recognized the center/position of the player and the brick and not the entire square/hitbox. I tried making a too long math calculation(100+ lines!) and still it gave me some bugs(like the ability to pass through it form the bottom but not from the top). My question is:
Can I find if an element is hovering an other (even for 1 pixel)? If yes can I make it on multiple bricks(with different ids)?

***UPDATE 21/10 8pm***
I went back to work and found a way to make "physics" by using a Mx and Mn variable for the player and the brick. With them I could find if the 2 elements but I think there is an easier way to make this, and still this has a bug: when I move on the right and hit the brick then I can only move left, when I move on the left and hit the brick then I can only go on the right, same as up and down, I can't figure out how to fix this...

```js
var brk = document.getElementById("brick");
var xBrk = Number(getComputedStyle(brk).getPropertyValue("left").replace('px', ""));
var xBrkMx = Number(getComputedStyle(brk).getPropertyValue("left").replace('px', "")) + Number(getComputedStyle(brk).getPropertyValue("width").replace('px', ""));
var yBrk = Number(getComputedStyle(brk).getPropertyValue("bottom").replace('px', ""));
var yBrkMx = Number(getComputedStyle(brk).getPropertyValue("bottom").replace('px', "")) + Number(getComputedStyle(brk).getPropertyValue("height").replace('px', ""));
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var xWin = Number(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("box")).getPropertyValue("width").replace('px', "")) - Number(getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("width").replace('px', ""));
var yWin = Number(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("box")).getPropertyValue("height").replace('px', "")) - Number(getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("height").replace('px', ""));
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);

function keyDown(e) {
  var player = document.getElementById("player");
  if (e.keyCode == 39) move(8, 0);
  if (e.keyCode == 37) move(-8, 0);
  if (e.keyCode == 40) move(0, -8);
  if (e.keyCode == 38) move(0, 8);
}

function move(X, Y) {
  var x = Number(getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("left").replace('px', "")) + X;
  var y = Number(getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("bottom").replace('px', "")) + Y;
  var xMn = x - X - Number(getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("width").replace('px', ""));
  var yMn = y - Y - Number(getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("height").replace('px', ""));
  var xMx = x + Number(getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("width").replace('px', "")) + Number(getComputedStyle(brk).getPropertyValue("width").replace('px', "")) - X;
  var yMx = y + Number(getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue("height").replace('px', "")) + Number(getComputedStyle(brk).getPropertyValue("height").replace('px', "")) - Y;
  if (xMx < xBrkMx || xMn > xBrk || yMx < yBrkMx || yMn > yBrk || ((xMx == xBrkMx && X == -8) || (yMx == yBrkMx && Y == -8) || (xMn == xBrk && X == 8) || (yMn == yBrk && Y == 8))) {
    if (x >= 0 && x <= xWin) player.style.left = x;
    if (y >= 0 && y <= yWin) player.style.bottom = y;
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 512;
  height: 256;
}

#player {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 8;
  height: 8;
  z-index: 2;
}

#world {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#brick {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 128px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 32;
  height: 32;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box">
    <div id="world">
      <div id="brick" />
    </div>
    <div id="player" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got thinking about this again.  What about taking this kind of approach instead?  It will be easier to add more objects later if you do something like this.  You won't be able to use the same id for all your bricks, etc. so you'll want to find a way around that, but this allows you to set your width/height in the CSS and position in the JS:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown",keyDown);

gameObjects = [];

const boxStyles = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("box"))

// This does the same thing as your code was doing, just in two steps
// Putting a + before an string implicitly converts it to a Number with a positive value
const SCREEN_WIDTH = +boxStyles.getPropertyValue("width").replace('px',"");
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = +boxStyles.getPropertyValue("height").replace('px',"");

function createGameObject(id, x, y) {
    const retVal = {
        "id": id,
        "element": document.getElementById(id),
        "x": x,
        "y": y,
        "width": document.getElementById(id).offsetWidth,
        "height": document.getElementById(id).offsetHeight,
        "setScreenPosition": function(){this.element.style.left = this.x + "px"; this.element.style.top = this.y + "px";},
        "moveLeft": function() {this.x -= this.width; this.setScreenPosition();},
        "moveRight": function() {this.x += this.width; this.setScreenPosition();},
        "moveUp": function() {this.y -= this.height; this.setScreenPosition();},
        "moveDown": function() {this.y += this.height; this.setScreenPosition();},
        "setXY": function(x, y) {this.x = x; this.y = y; this.setScreenPosition();}
    }
    retVal.setScreenPosition();
    gameObjects.push(retVal);
    return retVal;
}

const myPlayer = createGameObject("player", 0, 0);
const myBrick = createGameObject("brick", 128, 32);
const myWall = createGameObject("wall", 256, 128);

function keyDown(e) {

    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            moveLeft(myPlayer);
            break;
        case 38:
            moveUp(myPlayer);
            break;
        case 39:
            moveRight(myPlayer);
            break;
        case 40:
            moveDown(myPlayer);
            break;
    }
}

function moveLeft(gameObject) {
    let newX = gameObject.x - gameObject.width;

    if (newX < 0){
        console.log("Off the screen to the left.");
        return
    }
    // There are three lines here and they do the following:
    // Check if the gameObj[brick] will touch gameObject[Player] (x)
    // Check if the brick is in the way in the other dimension (y)
    // Check that the object we're comparing against isn't itself
    // I'm using filter to create an array of all objects in the way and then checking the length of that array.  An empty array means nothing in the way
    if (gameObjects.filter(gameObj=>gameObj.x <= newX && gameObj.x + gameObj.width >= gameObject.x && 
                                    gameObject.y >= gameObj.y && gameObject.y + gameObject.height <= gameObj.y + gameObj.height && 
                                    gameObj.id !== gameObject.id).length) {
        console.log("Hitting something on the left.");
        return;
    }
    gameObject.moveLeft();
}
function moveRight(gameObject) {
    let newX = gameObject.x + gameObject.width;

    if (newX >= SCREEN_WIDTH) {
        console.log("Off the screen to the right.");
        return;
    }
    if (gameObjects.filter(gameObj=>gameObj.x === newX && gameObject.y >= gameObj.y && 
                                    gameObject.y + gameObject.height <= gameObj.y + gameObj.height && 
                                    gameObj.id !== gameObject.id).length) {
        console.log("Hitting something on the right.")
        return;
    }
    gameObject.moveRight();
}
function moveUp(gameObject) {
    let newY = gameObject.y - gameObject.height;

    if (newY < 0) {
        console.log("Off the screen to the top.");
        return;
    }
    if (gameObjects.filter(gameObj=>gameObj.y <= newY && gameObj.y + gameObj.height >= gameObject.y &&
                                    gameObject.x >= gameObj.x && gameObject.x + gameObject.width <= gameObj.x + gameObj.width && 
                                    gameObj.id !== gameObject.id).length) {
        console.log("Hitting something above.");
        return;
    }
    gameObject.moveUp();
}
function moveDown(gameObject) {
    let newY = gameObject.y + gameObject.height;

    if (newY >= SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
        console.log("Off the screen to the bottom.");
        return;
    }
    if (gameObjects.filter(gameObj=>gameObj.y === newY && gameObject.x >= gameObj.x && 
                                    gameObject.x + gameObject.width <= gameObj.x + gameObj.width && 
                                    gameObj.id !== gameObject.id).length) {
        console.log("Hitting something below.");
        return;
    }
    gameObject.moveDown();
}
```

```css
#box {
    position:absolute
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:blue;
    width:512px;
    height:256px;
}
#player {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
    width:8px;
    height:8px;
    z-index:2;
}
#world {
    position:relative;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
#brick {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    z-index:1;
}

#wall {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:16px;
    height:48px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <div id="world">
        <div id="brick"></div>
        <div id="wall"/></div>
        <div id="player"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DadiB I added some comments to the code.  What do you mean about the offset?  The GameObject is just a bunch of data describing an object in the game.  I add them to the array so it can be looped through to check all objects on the board otherwise you'd end up with a whole bunch of code that does the same thing for each object on the board.

Comment: when I open the .html file in chrome there's a gap of 8pxs between the box and the 0 0 coordinate like this [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/lwJcjRW)

Comment: That's the user agent style sheet putting a 8px margin on ```body```.  Set ```body {margin:0;}``` in your CSS.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't thought about it!